# function mail()

Tags: php

Look this code:

```
$to="$email";
$sub="Hi";
$mex="hi <br />  \"<a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'</a>"\";
$int  = "From:h@h.com";
$int .= "Reply-To:try@try.com";
$int .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to, $sub, $mex, $int);
```

The error is on $mex, I think it's on `"<a href.."`

How to fix this?

Comment: you didn't even try to add a quote and use syntax highlighting to see code errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$to="$email";
$sub="Hi";
$mex="hi <br /> <a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'>something</a>";
$int  = "From:h@h.com";
$int .= "Reply-To:try@try.com";
$int .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to, $sub, $mex, $int);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$mex="hi <br />  \"<a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'></a>\"";
```

You misplaced the last backslash (`\`), it should be used to escape the `"`;

**Note**: Using a library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of `mail()` would make your life much easier. *For example* with adding **headers** (you should add CRLF after every header, as stated on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)). Honestly, I don't think beginners should use the `mail()` function at all. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 2):

Try so

```
$mex="hi <br />  \"<a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'</a>\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mex="hi <br />  \"<a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'</a>"\";
```

should be

```
$mex= "hi <br/><a href='http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod'>something here</a>";
```

No need to surround the `<a href ... ></a>` in quotes and you probably want to put something in the middle of the `>` and `</a>` to allow the user to click

Answer (score 0):

```
$mex="hi <br />  <a href=\"http://exemple.com/ver.php?id=$cod\">Your link text HERE</a>";
```

Also the headers should be ended by newlines:

```
$int  = "From:h@h.com\n\r";
$int .= "Reply-To:try@try.com\n\r";
$int .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n\r";
```

The `\n\r` newline is OS dependant and this works on Windows, for UNIX use only `\n` or `\n\n`.